# Trigger folding menu from a link click new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, triggers, click

I want to use the link on my index.html page to open a clickable folding menu on portfolio.html page once the link gets me to portfolio.html...

Index.html

```
<a class="sponsor-info" href="views/portfolio.html"></a>
```

Portfolio.html

```
<ul class="folding-menu">
  <li class="menu-item sponsors" id="all-metro">        
    <div class="folding-content"> Content </div>
  <li>
</ul>
```

Js script

```
$('.sponsor-info').click(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#all-metro').trigger('click');
   }, 1000);
});
```

The problem with my code that it works only for the same page. But, when it takes me from index.html to portfolio.html (to a new page) the menu won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing more about your setup, probably the easiest thing would be to use a query string argument in the url that you can detect on the other page to determine if the menu should be open or not. Something like the below should get you started:

First change your link to:

```
<a class="sponsor-info" href="views/portfolio.html?open=true"></a>
```

Then the javascript on the portfolio.html page should do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var query = window.location.search;
   if(query && query.length >0){
      var parts = query.split('=');
      var open = parts[0] === 'open' && parts[1] === 'true' ? true : false;
      if(open){
         $('#all-metro').trigger('click');
      }
   }
});
```

This should wait for the page to be ready, then get the query string from the window location and parse the string looking for the open parameter and then checks the value before triggering the click.

Comment: Do you have the javascript on the appropriate html page? Did you change the link? Did you try to debug it to find where it is failing?

Comment: Let me try to find where it's not working...
Basically, I'm just trying to trigger a click() event from a href.

Comment: But you are trying to do it across pages, which doesn't work directly, you have to come up with a work around similar to the above. When you click a link the javascript on the current page is unloaded and the new page is loaded by the browser along with any javascript or styles. If your javascript is in the first html page it is forgotten almost as soon as you click the link.

Comment: I added Js to the bottom of the page so it's in the priority.
I have a jquery plugin for my dropdown menu installed, which I'm trying to trigger from a link